# Troubles Displaying Arabic Text

Tags: php

I have this website, websiteaddress.com where I'm facing troubles displaying arabic text. Arabic text shows (?????) question marks only.

I had two sessions of chatting with support, but, no result so far.

**These options have been tested and didn't solve the issue:**

1. No database connection is actually established for Arabic text. All arabic text is static, no database entries. So, database encoding isn't an issue.
2. The site is based on wordpress, encoding in settings is set to "UTF-8". Also tried the ISO-8859-1, both gave the same result. (the arabic text doesn't come from the wordpress databse, it's hardcoded within the theme files)
3. added a default charset to htaccess to UTF-8 as well as ISO-8859-1.
4. Resent the headers using PHP with UTF-8 encoding and also tried ISO-8859-1.
5. changed the PHP.INI in my hosting root directory and also under this specific account root directory and changed the encoding from ISO to UTF-8.

So, all the above did not solve the issue.

Also, I have created two testing pages, with exactly the same text inside (in arabic): websiteaddress.com/test.html and websiteaddress.com/test.php .. both were the same pages, I just changed the extensions of the files. The html works fine and displays arabic. The php one doesn't work and displays questions marks.

This is basically the issue.

If anyone has any other option for me to try or know how to go about doing this, please let me know!

I have searched alot on stackoverflow and found alot of solutions, mostly all the above solutions were mentioned in some questions on stackoverflow. But, none of them answered my question, hence the post here..

Thanks and have a great day everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by my hosting provider, just in case anyone need this. This is their reply:

I checked the php.ini and the changes were not made in there, so I changed them for you. I also edited the following in your php.ini. exif.encode_unicode I set it to UTF-8 and uncommented it. Now the arabic is rendering at: websiteaddress.com/test.php and websiteaddress.com/test.html You can add the following to your .htaccess to get a different php version rendered. The following code is for 5.3. AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php