# How to get Arabic filenames charset display correctly using PHP readdir() function

Tags: php, filesystems, arabic

[snapshot of the result i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0PpW.png)

that's what I tried and ended with question marks like the snapshot above , I don't know how to get rid of these question marks and get the correct arabic charset instead , anyone help

```
 if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $file_utf8 = iconv( "CP1256", "UTF-8", $file );
        echo  $file_utf8 . "<br>";
      }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
```

Comment: have you checked these [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462631/php-file-get-content-arabic-characters) and [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677350/troubles-displaying-arabic-text) and [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309496/php-print-arabic-string) ?

Comment: yes, none of these answers are helping.